# how to find average of vector of averages of multiple samples in R

Tags: r, arrays, loops

I want to generate 8820 samples of size 139 each with binomial distribution. I then want to find the average of each sample, put all of these averages in a single array and then find the average of said array. Here's my code:

```
set.seed(1865)

for(i in 1:8820){
  name <- paste("V", i, sep = "")
  assign(name, rbinom(139, 46, 0.83))
  avgs = c(mean(name[i]))
  avg = mean(avgs)
}

print(avg)
```

However, I get `NA` error after the `print`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create your 8820 samples in your workspace.

You could better use `replicate`.

```
n <- 8820

set.seed(1865)
samps <- replicate(n, rbinom(139, 46, 0.83), simplify=FALSE) |>
  setNames(paste0('V', sprintf('%04d', seq_len(n))))
```

Gives a list.

```
str(samps)
# List of 8820
# $ V0001: int [1:139] 39 39 37 35 39 34 38 43 33 41 ...
# $ V0002: int [1:139] 43 41 39 37 36 41 38 35 40 39 ...
# $ V0003: int [1:139] 41 37 40 34 38 39 44 40 37 39 ...
# $ V0004: int [1:139] 38 43 40 39 40 39 39 39 33 39 ...
# $ V0005: int [1:139] 37 42 38 38 40 38 40 43 39 39 ...
# $ V0006: int [1:139] 40 40 40 41 38 39 40 41 39 39 ...
# $ V0007: ...
```

Calculate means.

```
sapply(samps, mean)
#    V0001    V0002    V0003    V0004    V0005    V0006    V0007 
# 37.88489 38.10791 38.14388 38.04317 38.31655 38.37410 38.07194 
#    V0008    V0009    V0010    V0011    V0012    V0013    V0014 
# 38.58273 37.90647 37.94245 38.17986 38.28058 38.33813 38.28058 
#    V0015    V0016    V0017    V0018    V0019    V0020    V0021 
# 38.51799 37.92086 38.20863 38.01439 38.05036 38.48921 38.58273 
# ...
```

You probably meant a **vector** you want to put the samples into?

```
main <- do.call(c, samps)

length(main)/n
# [1] 139
```

Calculate mean.

```
mean(main)
# [1] 38.181
```

You can still bloat your workspace then using:

```
# list2env(samps, .GlobalEnv)  ## not recommended!
```

If you are looking for a **8820 x 139 matrix**, just don't use `simplify=`.

```
set.seed(1865)
m <- t(replicate(n, rbinom(139, 46, 0.83)) )
dim(m)
# [1] 8820  139
```